# Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, syntax-error

I have tables called `Table_Stories` and `Table_Images` in my database which are connected with keys. I insert values into them with a stored procedure I created.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].Table_Stories
(
    [StoryID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [ID] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Table_Users(ID),
    [StoryText] NVARCHAR(120),
    [imgID] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Table_Images (imgID)
)
```

CODE:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UserStory  
    @ID [INT],
    @storyText [NVARCHAR](120),
    @img [VARCHAR](MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StoryID INT, @ImageID INT;

    INSERT INTO Table_Images ([img]) VALUES (@img)

    SET @ImageID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    INSERT INTO Table_Stories ([ID], [StoryText], [imgID]) 
    VALUES (@ID, @storyText, @ImageID)

    SET @StoryID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    INSERT INTO Table_Stories ([StoryID]) 
    VALUES (@StoryID)

    INSERT INTO dbo.imagesInStories (StoryID, imgID)
    VALUES (@StoryID, @ImageID);

    SELECT * 
    FROM Table_Stories 
    WHERE StoryID = @StoryID AND imgID = @ImageID;
END
```

I run:

```
exec UserStory 1, 'I welcom you to my trip', 'Chadmie.jpg'
```

and get this error :

> Msg 545, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UserStory, Line 14 [Batch Start Line 291]
>   Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'Table_Stories' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.

I don't understand what that error means and how to fix it.

p.s
I cant insert all the sql code here (not as I did) its taking me too much time due to the red error that is showing no matter what I do trying to fix the question code.

Comment: It looks like you have IDENTITY_INSERT set to ON for Table_Stories. You can resolve this by setting this to Off or include the Identity column in your insert statement. When this is ON, you need to explicitly specify the value for your identity columns in your INSERT statement.

You can read more [here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-545.aspx)

Comment: Show Table_Stories `create table` script. I don't understand neither of two sequential inserts into it.

Comment: Thank for who edited it, I wish I know how and not cause trouble in this wonderful site. @IvanStarostin  - here I did it.

Comment: @SaravanaKannadasanGandhi - Hi , I dont know why but when I insert manualy to [Table_Stories] it is on off and had to to write this code before: SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Table_Stories] ON
GO. so now I don't understant from the page you sent me what to do.

Comment: You need SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Table_Stories] ON whenever you want to manually insert a value for your identity column (StoryID) .. Happy to help!

Comment: I dont understand why you are doing the second insert into Table_Stories. Even if you fix everything else with IDENTITY_INSERT this insert will fail because you are trying to write a second row into the table with the same identity key that was created during your first insert.

Comment: @TomC Hi, Table_Stories has its own ID =  [StoryID] int not null identity(1,1) primary key. my second  SET #StoryID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()  was a mistake, but I still can't understand why.

Comment: If we are still talking about the code in your question, you are doing three steps. 1) `INSERT INTO Table_Stories` which will save the row with a new identity key. then 2) `SET @StoryID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();` reads back this identity key, and 3) `INSERT INTO Table_Stories ([StoryID])` tries to write a new row, with a duplicate key that was just written (fail), without any other columns, and without `IDENTITY_INSERT ON` (second fail). The answer given below has removed these unnecessary steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestions:

1. Rename `ID` into `UserID` - it's name is extremely confusing now for table `UserStory`
2. Put all data modifications into transaction
3. Remove redundant second insert into `Table_Stories` - I don't know why did you write it for
4. Add some verb to proc's name, make it something like `EditUserStory` or `UserStory_UPD` or whatever
5. Specify object's schema event if it is `dbo`, don't use `select *`

e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UserStory_UPD
    @UserID INT,
    @storyText NVARCHAR(120),
    @img VARCHAR(MAX) -- I assume this is a path or an URL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StoryID INT, @ImageID INT;

    BEGIN TRY
      /* params validation stuff */

      BEGIN TRAN

      INSERT INTO dbo.Table_Images ([img]) 
      VALUES (@img)

      SET @ImageID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

      INSERT INTO dbo.Table_Stories ([UserID], [StoryText], [imgID]) 
      VALUES (@UserID, @storyText, @ImageID)

      SET @StoryID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

      INSERT INTO dbo.imagesInStories (StoryID, imgID)
      VALUES (@StoryID, @ImageID);

      COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
      IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRAN
      /* raiserror stuff or THROW */
    END CATCH

    SELECT s.StoryID, s.UserID, s.StoryText, s.ImgID
    FROM dbo.Table_Stories s
    WHERE s.StoryID = @StoryID
END
```

Comment: ,I did and I uderstand everything but last part, (which I choose not to use) :  <!-- language: sql  --> COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
      IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRAN
      /* raiserror stuff or THROW */
    END CATCH